# Variable Values are not rendering to the JSF tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am getting data from MySQL database through the EJB java method loadGradeSubjects().All the necessary data come from the database and those are assign to instance variables. The issue is in JSF interface. That assign variables are rendering to the interface but those are not rendering to the relevant tags. Below I will  add my JSF interface

```
<p:dialog header="Time Table Setup" width="50%" widgetVar="timeTableSetup" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" responsive="true">

        <p:outputPanel id="timeTableSetupPanel" style="text-align:left;width: 100%;border: none;">

            <p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width:auto;height:90vh;border: none;">

                <h:form id="formThree">
                    <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />
                    <p:panel style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Year :" for="attendYear" style="font-weight: bold;">
                                    <p:inputText id="attendYear" style="width: 100%;" value="#{TimeTableManager.yearValue}" readonly="true"/>
                                </p:outputLabel>


                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Class :" for="selectedClass" style="font-weight: bold;">
                                    <p:inputText id="selectedClass" style="width: 100%;" value="#{TimeTableManager.classId}" readonly="true"/>
                                </p:outputLabel>


                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel style="margin-top: 1%; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:dataTable var="ts" value="#{TimeTableManager.selectedDataCellIds}" style="width: 100%"  id="timetablesetuptable" resizableColumns="false"  reflow="false" paginator="false" rows="8" rowsPerPageTemplate="200,400,600,800">
                                    <p:column headerText="Date" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;font-weight: bold" >
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ts.date}" /><br/>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Time Slot" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;font-weight: bold">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ts.timeSlot}" /><br/>
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel style="margin-top: 1%; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Subject:" for="assignSubject" style="font-weight: bold;" />

                                <p:selectOneMenu id="assignSubject"  autoWidth="false" effect="slide" value="#{TimeTableManager.gradeSubject}" style="width: 100%;" >

                                    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{TimeTableManager.loadSubjectTeacherNames()}" render="assignSubjectTeacher12" />

                                    <f:selectItems value="#{TimeTableManager.gradeSubjectNameList}" />

                                </p:selectOneMenu>


                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:outputLabel value="Subject Teacher:" for="assignSubjectTeacher12" style="font-weight: bold;"/>

                                <p:selectOneMenu id="assignSubjectTeacher12" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Teacher !"  autoWidth="false" effect="slide" value="#{TimeTableManager.subjectTeacher}" style="width: 100%;" >

                                    <f:selectItems value="#{TimeTableManager.subjectTeacherNameList}" />

                                </p:selectOneMenu>



                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%;text-align: end" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">
                                    <p:commandButton type="button"  styleClass="blue-btn flat"  icon="ui-icon-plus" style="width: 50%" value="ADD">
                                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="loadtimetablesetup" listener="#{TimeTableManager.addSubjectAndTeacherToTimeTableSetup()}" />
                                    </p:commandButton>

                                </p:panelGrid>

                            </h:panelGroup>

                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel style="margin-top: 1%; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:dataTable var="ts2" value="#{TimeTableManager.selectedDataCellsToUpdate}" style="width: 100%"  id="loadtimetablesetup" resizableColumns="false"  reflow="false" paginator="false" rows="8" rowsPerPageTemplate="200,400,600,800">
                                    <!--                                        <p:column headerText="Time Slot" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;">
                                                                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{ts2.isSelected}" />
                                                                            </p:column>-->
                                    <p:column headerText="Time Slot" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ts2.daysPeriodId}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Subject" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ts2.cellSubjectName}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Teacher" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: top;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ts2.cellSubjectTeacher}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                </p:dataTable>

                                <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%;text-align: end" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                                    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-delete" styleClass="secondary flat" style="width: 20%" value="CLEAR">

                                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="loadtimetablesetup" listener="#{TimeTableManager.clearSubjectAndTeacherFromTimeTableSetup()}" />

                                    </p:commandButton>

                                </p:panelGrid>

                            </h:panelGroup>

                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel> 

                    <p:panel style="margin-top: 1%">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%;text-align: end" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>

                                <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 100%;text-align: end" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group">

                                    <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('timeTableSetup').hide()" icon="ui-icon-save" styleClass="green-btn flat" style="width: 50%" value="SAVE">

                                        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="AssignClassTeachers" listener="#{TimeTableManager.saveSelectedTeacherToTimeTable()}" />

                                    </p:commandButton>

                                </p:panelGrid>

                            </h:panelGroup>

                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel>

                    <!--</p:outputPanel>-->

                </h:form>

            </p:scrollPanel>

        </p:outputPanel>

    </p:dialog>
```

In above code varables like TimeTableManager.classId,TimeTableManager.gradeSubjectNameList,TimeTableManager.subjectTeacherNameList are have values. But the issue is those values are not rendering to the JSF tags. Now I add How I call the dialog box to open.

```
              <p:commandLink oncomplete="PF('timeTableSetup').show()" update="formThree" actionListener="#{TimeTableManager.loadGradeSubjects()}">

                                    Add Teachers To Time Table

                                    <!--<p:commandButton type="button" style="width: 20%" styleClass="secondary flat" icon="ui-icon-add" value="ADD OR EDIT" />-->
                                  
                                </p:commandLink>
```

I use command link because commant button does not work properly. I tried clean and build deleting target folder changing variable names but nothing worked. Can Some one help me on this issue

Comment: Please carefully read [ask], [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Then **edit** and improve your question in order to get better answers sooner. The cause of the problem is not visible in the information provided so far and the code snippets shown so far contain extremely a lot of irrelvant noise which do definitely not contribute to the described problem. Ignoring other's guidance and creating the same question over and over is only going to work against you, don't do that.